# Режим обслуживания Laravel

Tags: laravel

Включаю режим обслуживания в Laravel. В итоге после обновления, без отключения этого режима, нельзя ничего самому просмотреть.

Можно ли добавлять определенные страницы в исключение этого режима? К примеру,  страницу авторизации.  А потом отключить его для администратора. Или я неверно понимаю смысл этого режима?

Comment: Какие "обновления" вы имеете в виду?

Comment: К примеру, обновление исходного кода

Comment: А как вы его меняете на production? Как у вас происходит переключение между релизами?

Comment: Локальная версия связана с гитом, разработку веду на локалке. Потом синхронизирую код на удаленном сервере с локальной версией по sftp

Comment: Ну, начнем с того, что у вас проблемы с выкладкой сайта. По SFTP файлы можно закачивать, конечно, но не в папку с работающим приложением.

Comment: А как это можно сделать правильно? Я бы подключил гит и к удаленному серверу, но хостинг накладывает некие ограничения.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55887/discussion-between-zhukov-roman-and--).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы можете использовать WhiteList для доступа к сайту, который находится в режиме обслуживания.

Хорошо описано здесь:
https://toniperic.com/2015/12/01/maintenance-mode-and-whitelists-in-laravel-5

Похуже здесь:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-maintenance-mode